# This a question in context to rolling friction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics

Why is the velocity at the point of contact (between wheel and surface when the condition is rolling without slipping) with respect to the surface remains zero all the times although the center of wheel moves forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the velocity at point  is non zero slipping is occurring, but since velocity is zero it is rolling.

The definition of a body that is rolling is that there is no apparent slipping between point of contact.

Hope that answers something.

Answer (score 0):

The velocity difference at the point of contact between wheel and surface doesn't have to remain zero, that's the point e.g. of [ABS brakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-lock_braking_system).

Rolling is *defined* as the case when it does. You can [read about this on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling), and understand how velocity can differ between contact point and center of wheel:
[image]

Finally, *rolling friction* is related with the fact that during real instances rolling, there will be dissipation taking place.